# What's the cause of this issue with my laptop? Word and File Explorer give blank errors. Pictures inside

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word, windows-explorer

This issue has happened a couple of times over the past few days. When I restart the laptop, the problem disappears, but it always comes back eventually.

When I click on Word, it doesn't open properly. Sometimes it gives the following blank error message:

[image]

Other times, it gives an error message with just the word 'memory':

[image]

The box at the bottom is always blank, but clicking on it makes the error message disappear. As you can see, there are no error codes or anything else I can search up. That's why I'm asking here.

Another issue which seems to coincide with the Word problems is to do with the file explorer. The file and folder names will disappear, and only thumbnails will be visible. Folder names are still visible in the address bar at the top. Again, this problem fixes itself with a restart, but comes back after some time:

[image]

I've never had these problems on a laptop before, and honestly I have no clue what could be causing them. Any insight would be great, thanks in advance

EDIT: Some background on the laptop itself:

It's only about a year old
i3 (5th gen I think)
4GB RAM
1TB HDD

I'm not sure of the specific model number, but it's a Dell Inspiron 15 3000 series

Comment: If you create a new user, does the problem exhibit itself, on that new user?  **If you have a 5th generation Intel product, then your device, is older then a year.**  I assume you purchased the device new.

Comment: @Ramhound yes, I bought the device brand new. I think it was old stock they were getting rid of, since it was on offer when I bought it, but still brand new.

I'll try making a new user and report back with whether or not the problem persists

Comment: Does not change the fact, most of the 5th generation products, were released back in the Q1 2015.  **We are talking more then 3 years.**  It's possible you are mistaken about which CPU you have, only you can determine if that is the case, and update your question as appropriate.

Comment: OK, I'll sort that out and then update the question. Thanks.